# Spring Architecture Questions: is Service needed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and I'm creating a REST-Service.
I wonder what the Service-Layer is for (@Service).
Currently I encapsulate my DAOs with that Layer.
So for example my PersonController receives a PUT, calls the PersonService which calls the DAO which finally saves the person in my database.

I also saw some examples in the www. (https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/how-to-use-spring-component-repository-service-and-controller-annotations/)

I also have read this question here: [Is this a good Spring Architecture (include testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877060/is-this-a-good-spring-architecture-include-testing)

Do I even need the Services, if it only calls the DAO like:

```
public void save(Person p) {
    personDAO.save(p);
}
```

?

I don't really see what the advantage of this is. I create classes which actually do nothing... Or is it just a architecture standard because additional business logic will be in this layer too?

---

Also... when I have several services like personService, familyService, animalService, etc. and they all have some method signatures that are the same and some which aren't... is it useful to use Interfaces here?

When I create Interfaces like: Saveable, Loadable, Deleteable (does this even make sense?) - how do I use them correctly? Do I create a new Interface for every service that extends the Interfaces I desire? Like a PersonServiceInterface that extends Loadable and Deleteable and I implement it in my PersonService?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With extremely simple code you can get away with a lot of things. However once you're actually writing something more realistic you'll see the advantages in different architectural choices. This would probably be more suitable in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. But actually I'm creating a REST-Service that doesn't really do anything else than reading/updating/deleting from a db. I think there are realistic use-cases for that. (e.g. society management)

Comment: Well nobody's forcing you to write code you don't think is necessary. A simple CRUD layer doesn't require much, there are probably automated tools to create one so you don't even need to write the boilerplate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not feel the need for a service layer, then chances are high your controllers are performing way more business logic than they should.

adding a service layer in between allows for dedicated tests of pure frontend (controller handle request and response wiring only / services handle the business logic/ repositories persist and query the data).

so rule of thumb - it is much easier to have many services handle fractions of your logic than to stuff everything into your controllers

i am not sure what you are trying to solve with the interfaces you introduce - i do not think it makes sense to re-invent the Repository interface on top of your services. If your services only forward to repositories directly then there is no use in having them anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it okay for a Service to call other services? Or do I make my Controller know the other Controller which knows the Service I need and call the method from there? For example I need to get some information before I call my actual service. e.g.  "return billService.load(new BillId(memberController.loadMember(memberId), year));"

Comment: it is ok to chain as many services as you like. you only need to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Won't that grow together my vertical separations in the service layer? When I have more and more code wouldn't that make it difficult to split it up on multiple servers?

Comment: you can split away services into their own module and share them between your microservices. You can add configuration classes per module to customise them per service

Comment: So that is the correct way to do it and my Controllers are not allowed to know each other?

Comment: they should not need to know each other to call for business code - there still might be cases where they might need to know each other for other reasons (link generation)

Comment: Okay, thank you. May you provide an answer for my question about interfaces? (It would be great if you add that to your post via editing...)

Comment: @DerKnecht I'd suggest a facade rather than having services call other services.